# Strange result when reading data from browser cache

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

In an experimental extension I am working on I use a function to get the source of a webpage and assign it to a variable. It worked perfectly fine. However I want to change the way it works and get the content from a txt file.

I am hosting a txt file like: `http//1.2.3.4/1.txt`.

What I want is to assign the contents of this txt file to a variable.

Function is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qumsm/.

(Function is not mine. I got it from another extension xpi which I cant remember right now. Respects to the coder of it.)

The function produces `"ÿþP"` this result which I dont get.

Comment: You want to extract data from the browser cache - so why don't you say that instead of letting people guess it from your code?

Comment: I am sorry If I caused trouble. Since I am new to this whole xul-js-firefox thing I did not know it is called "extracting data from browser cache".

Comment: In other words, you copied that code from somewhere and you don't know what it does?

Comment: No, I know what it does but I want to learn how does it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [byte order mark](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), the file you are looking at seems to be using UTF-16 LE encoding. You need to use [nsIConverterInputStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIConverterInputStream) instead of `nsIScriptableInputStream` when reading in that data and specify the correct encoding to convert from. `nsIScriptableInputStream` is only useful when reading in ANSI data, not Unicode. See [code example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Reading_textual_data#Reading_strings).